# iOS: How to tell if you scroll past the a certain row in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need a way to detect if I scroll past the 5th row in a UITableView. Once I past the 5th row I want to call a method. I have no idea how to do this or where to begin. I will post the UITableView code. If anyone can help me I will deeply appreciate it.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
ListingCell  *cell ;
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListingCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 100;
}

-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 20;
}
```

Comment: If all your rows are of the same height than it should be simple enough to implement answer from Putz1103 below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is implement the UIScrollViewDelegate method `-scrollViewDidScroll`.  Then you can manually calculate anything you want from the current UITableView `contentOffset` property.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)inScrollView
{
    int currentOffsetY = inScrollView.contentOffset.y;

    //Now use that y position to figure out if you have scrolled past where you want.
}
```

You may also want a boolean so only call the "past here" method once.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    CGRect row = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
    if (tableView.contentOffset.y > CGRectGetMaxY(row)) {
        // you did it
    }
}
```

Or `CGRectGetMinY`, depending on what *exactly* you're trying to achieve.